# Why am I receiving a TypeError when trying to use imapclient?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am new to Python, and I am attempting to write code to get me into my gmail inbox, following along with a Udemy course. I have successfully installed imapclient, and importing impapclient does not return any error so I think I am okay on that.

When I go to write my next line of code `conn = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)` and enter it, it gives me a Type Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    conn = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
  File "C:\Users\china\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 254, in __init__
    self._imap = self._create_IMAP4()
  File "C:\Users\china\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 288, in _create_IMAP4
    return tls.IMAP4_TLS(self.host, self.port, self.ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\china\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 44, in __init__
    imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "C:\Users\china\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
TypeError: open() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I know that both ssl=True and 'imap.gmail.com' are both required arguments, so I have not tried taking either out. I only have two lines of code, and I am following the exact code on the Udemy course, so I am not sure how to resolve this myself.

Comment: I believe you have an older version of the `imapclient` module that doesn't support Python 3.9 (specifically, it's not expecting that `timeout` parameter that was added to `IMAP4.open()` in 3.9.

Comment: I just pip installed the imapclient yesterday. After checking, it is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
The problem is that imapclient is only officially supported until Python 3.7, so you could try using imapclient with Python 3.7.

Or you could use imaplib module. It is a bit more complicated, but I tried using imaplib and pyzmail module (to make the text more readable)

```
import imaplib
import pyzmail

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('IMAP_SERVER')
server.login('email@example.com', 'password')
server.select("INBOX")
typ, data = server.search(None, "ALL")
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = server.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(data[0][1])
    print('THIS IS MESSAGE NO. ' + str(num))
    if(message.text_part != None):
        print(message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset))
    elif(message.html_part != None):
        print(message.html_part.get_payload().decode(message.html_part.charset))

server.close()
server.logout()
```

im not an expert at Python, so using pyzmail might not be the optimal solution, but it worked for me using Python 3.9

- for IMAP_SERVER you have to insert the right IMAP server domain name (like imap.gmail.com for gmail accounts)
- and you have to enter your real email address and password (or get the password with input())

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. And it has been fixed in IMAPClient 2.2.0.
https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/releases.html